# How to uniquely identify whether two resultsets are equal?

Tags: java, sql

Is there a particular way to identify whether two result sets are equal?

problem is that I can't access two result set at the same time. So it's better for me to create a hashvalue for resultset1 and store it and get the later resultset2 and create hashvalue2 and check whther they are equal.

I tried to serialize the resultset objects and get a hashvalue of that object. But that didn't work since ResultSet objects can't be serialized. (I tried using java)

Comment: you should use ResultSetCompare class.see this article http://incubator.apache.org/jena/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/resultset/ResultSetCompare.html

Comment: [Comparing result sets ][1] Please check this link, it might help your cause.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582093/comparing-resultsets-in-jdbc

Comment: @ZazGmy thanks for the answers guys. I have a little problem here since I can't directly access two resultsets at the same time.It's better if I can create a hashvalue1 for a ResultSet1 and then later execute the query2 to get the ResultSet2 and generate the hashvalue2 see whether the two hash values are equal. (I edited the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to store one or both of the hash values in a variable or table: for example, you could find the first value and store it in a global variable, then pull that value into the end of the code to find the 2nd value and then compare the two.  If you store them in a table with a datetime stamp, you can track when changes are made over time.

Comment: Yes that's the problem I'm having. But I need a fast mechanism to create a hash value. Since if the resultset is large in size, the time to create a hashvalue may take very long. There is a built in function called DBMS_SQLHASH to do this but unfortunately I'm using MySQL database in my application.